# Find median value across multiple columns in a Dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a Dask dataframe with three columns, width, height and length.
I need to create a fourth column, which is the median of the three.

My code with regular pandas df doesn't work as median is not a function in Dask.

```
columns_to_sum = ['weight', 'height', 'length']
df['median'] = df[columns_to_sum].median(axis=1)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Median, I believe, is a fairly hard to implement as a distributed algorithm.  As such, I don't think dask has an implementation.  For more context I would recommend reading:
https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/46 and https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1225

Comment: I think maybe I don't need to median, essentially I just need to get the column value that is not the min or max, but wanted to find a smart way if there is any. :)

Comment: You could get the mean :)

```In [16]: import dask

In [17]: ddf = dask.datasets.timeseries()

In [18]: ddf.x.mean().compute()
Out[18]: -7.704277646351872e-08
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that parallel median is hard, in this case the question asker is asking about median across columns.  This is easy because for every row we have all of the data already in memory.

If this doesn't already exist then this should be added to Dask Dataframe.  If you want to raise an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new that would be welcome.

As a short-term workaround, you can always use Pandas functions and map_partitions

```
def f(df: pandas.DataFrame, columns: list) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    df = df.copy()  # dask prefers that you not mutate inputs
    df["median"] = df[columns].median(axis=1)

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(f, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
```